Is there a way to change the iteration of a for loop that is iterating through a file to a different line?
I am making a test coding language and I need to code a goto statement (I know while and for are alternatives, but I want to use goto for this). Is there a way to go back in the file?
Here is my code:
with open("code.txt", "r") as file:
  for line in file:
    line = line.split(" ")
    if line[0] == "ADD":
      cmd.ADD(int(line[1]), int(line[2]), line[3])
    elif line[0] == "OUT":
      cmd.OUT(line[1])
    elif line[0] == "GOTO":
      #code for changing lines here

cmd is the class holding all the commands.
I tried using seek() but it changes the file pointer for each byte, not line.
EDIT: i managed to fix it by counting the length of each line and adding it to a current_pos variable which is used to store labels. its hard to explain so i will just add the code and hope you understand.
labels = {}

with open("code.txt", "r+") as file:
  current_pos = 0
  for line in file:
    current_pos = len(line)
    line = line.split(" ")
    if line[0] == "ADD":
      cmd.ADD(int(line[1]), int(line[2]), line[3])
    elif line[0] == "OUT":
      cmd.OUT(line[1])
    elif line[0] == "GOTO":
      if line[1] in labels: #checks if you are referencing a label
        file.seek(labels[line[1]]) # changes the pointer pos to just after the label
    elif line[0][0] == "@": #@ is the identifier saying that this line is a label
      labels[line[0].replace("\n", "")] = current_pos #storing the label's position


Can you give a concrete input example and expected results for it? Like what is  following the GOTO, and how should it be interpreted? Also, why do you mean with "(will be in the cmd class if possible)"?

Perhaps use lines = file.readlines() to load the lines into a list.  Then have your programming language manipulate the line directly.  When complete, file.writelines() can push the data back out to the file.

I tend to recommend lines = list(file) for code written in modern Python
